# Including classes done right/wrong

Tags: php, class, oop, include

### **This works...**

*classes/API.class.php*

```
abstract class API
{
    stuff.
}
```

*api.php*

```
require_once 'classes/API.class.php';

class MyAPI extends API
{
    stuff;
}
$API = new MyAPI();
```

---

### **This doesn't work...**

...but leads to a "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class API in D:\xampp-..."

*classes/API.class.php*

```
abstract class API
{
    stuff.
}
```

*classes/MyAPI.class.php*

```
class MyAPI extends API
{
    stuff;
}
```

*api.php*

```
require_once 'classes/API.class.php';
require_once 'classes/MyAPI.class.php';

$API = new MyAPI();
```

---

Can you explain me **why?** 
And how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick suggestion, but have a look into Composer for its ability to handle autoloading for you. That way you don't need to do any `require` statements. https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

But to your original question. The typical way to do it is to `require_once` the abstract class from the definition of the concrete class and then `require_once` the concrete class from where you intend to use it. Be aware that the path is based on the original calling document, so saying `require_once "API.php";` from `/classes/MyApi.php` and being called from `/api.php` won't work, so use `require_once __DIR__ . '/API.php';` in `/classes/MyApi.php`.

Comment: thanks. found out that my original "not working" was based on a unrelated failure by myself

Comment: Glad you got everything sorted :-)